# C# Class with Sub-Items

Tags: c#, class, subitem

Let's say, I want to have a main class with many sub-classes in it, the sub classes all with the same properties/methods, and I need to access them in many different other code parts.

Example:
Main class: Country

Sub classes / Items: Germany, Netherlands, Great Britian, France, ...

Then defining individual properties for each Country, like Population, Units, ...

So later in code I can access it like

```
if (Country.France.Units < Country.Germany.Units)
Console.WriteLine("foo");
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers everyone, CodeCaster's solution is perfect for my purpose. The others are right too, parsing the dictionary by string values is just less work...

Comment: It looks like a little bit strange design - subclass for each country you will use. Why don't just use something like `var france = new Country() {Name = "France", Units = ...}` and so on?

Comment: what makes you think you need a static class here?

Comment: You can inherit from your main class for each of your subclasses, that way the properties of the MustInherit class (in this case, Country) become properties in each of the other classes (I.e France inherits Country, Germany inherits country, etc.)

Comment: I agree with Andy, just instantiate a new instance of your main class for each country.

Comment: actually this is almost a textbook example of class instantiation. You would have a country class, and each specific country would be an instance of that class. including the name is good (you could override ToString() if you want/need) and you can name the instances, so instead of `Country.France.Units` you would first do `Country France = new Country()` and then you could just say `if (France.Units < Germany.Units)`.

Comment: @Comments: This is what I would do usually. But it doesn't work in my case. I'd like to define different countries once and then use them in many other classes, like not only once and right after the definition...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do this, because then for every country added you'd have to recompile, meaning you can't automatically link data loaded from an external data source to a statically-typed property.

Use a dictionary instead:

```
var countries = new Dictionary<string, Country>();

// ...

if (countries["France"].Units < ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Especially to solve current task you can create a class Country with private constructor and static properties for each country.

```
public class Country
{
    private Country()
    {
    }

    public int Population {get; private set;}

    // Static members

    public static Country USA {get; private set;}
    public static Country Italy {get; private set;}

    static Country()
    {
        USA = new Country { Population = 100000 };
        Italy = new Country { Population = 50000 };
    }
}
```

You can access it by the following code

```
Country.USA.Population < Country.Italy.Population
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ It says 'member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type'

Comment: The sample was written in the place and I don't validate it, so the static keyword for static constructor was missed.

Comment: Code fixed, you can use it

Answer (score 1):

What you want sounds very similar to the `Color` struct.  It has a large pre-defined set of classes but still allows for "custom" colors.

Unlike `Color`, however, `Country` has properties that could change over time, and may benefit from having an external data source that could be updated. There are also a finite number of countries, so you can optimize memory by not having thousands of "France" instances floating around.

One pattern that would fit that is a [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).  You can minimize the number of objects floating around by using a factory method but still allow easy access to a pre-defined set of countries:

```
public class Country
{
    // properties of a Country:
    public int Population {get; private set;}
    public string Units {get; private set;}
    // etc.

    // Factory method/fields follows

    // storage of created countries
    private static Dictionary<string, Country> _Countries = new Dictionary<string,Country>();

    public static Country GetCountry(string name)
    {
        Country country;
        if(_Countries.TryGetValue(name, out country))
            return country;
        //else
        country = new Country();
        // load data from external source
        _Countries[name] = country;
        return country;
    }

    public static Country France { get {return GetCountry("France");} }
    public static Country Germany { get {return GetCountry("Germany");} }
}
```

Some caveats with the design as-is:

- It is not thread-safe.  You'll need to add the proper thread safety.
- Countries are not eternal - what would you do if a pre-define country no longer exists?
- Ideally, the factory would be a separate class so you can de-couple the `Country` class from the factory, but I think `Country.France` looks better than `CountryFactory.France`

Comment: Thank you Sir for this advanced solution, I was thinking about something similar to Color / ConsoleColor too, but somehow didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the string parsing of the dictionary, and your list is relatively small, you can just do something like this:

```
List<Country> counties = new List<Country>();
countries.Add(France as Country);
countries.Add(Germany as Country);
...

var France = countries.FirstOrDefault(t => t is France);
```

Comment: That's not boxing, that's [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). Boxing wraps a _value_ type.

Comment: You're correct, @CodeCaster I didn't realize it only applied to value types, guess I never read the fine print

Comment: What exactly is the type of `France` and `Germany` in this code? And why the use of `as`?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet per the question, `France` and `Germany` are sub-classes of the `Country` class. `as` is a way of casting the objects to their base type

Comment: If they're subclasses then there's no need to use `as`. Also, creating a subclass for each country is probably not a good idea - creating an instance of a `Country` class for each country would be better, assuming that countries all have the same properties (just with different values).